# Why does viewModelScope cancel itself when its child fails?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have this piece of code:

```
private fun fetchData() {
    viewModelScope.launch(ioDispatcher + exceptionHandler) {
        launch { repo.refreshData() }

        repo.fetchLocalData().collect { data ->
            liveData.postValue(data)
        }
    }
}
```

And if `repo.refreshData()` throws an exception, the whole scope is cancelled and  `liveData.postValue(data)` is never called. However, if I wrap `repo.refreshData()` in `runCatching{}`, this never happens.

From my understanding of [exceptions in coroutines](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/exceptions-in-coroutines-ce8da1ec060c), viewModelScopel uses SupervisorJob, and SupervisorJob doesn't cancel itself or its children when one of its children fails.

Any idea what I might be getting wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`SupervisorJob` is only a part of `viewmodelScope`s context.

Your `launch` block creates a new empty `Job()` that is not a supervisor so any exceptions caused by it or its children cancel it (and all children within: in your case repo `launch` and `collect`).

Those exceptions also get propagated upwards to `viewModelScope` but it doesn't get cancelled since it's a supervisor.

Link you provided does explain it. You have to create another supervisor scope where cancellation of a child doesn't collapse entire scope with its children:

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch(ioDispatcher + exceptionHandler) {
        supervisorScope {
            launch { repo.refreshData() }

            repo.fetchLocalData().collect { data ->
                liveData.postValue(data)
            }
        }
    }
```

edit: updated code; `SupervisorJob()` works only if its used when creating a coroutine scope, it has no effect when used as an argument of `launch` or `async` builders.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried `viewModelScope.launch(SupervisorJob() + ioDispatcher + logExceptionHandler) {}`, and the cancellation is still happening. Do I have to use the SupervisorJob alone?

Comment: @X09 my bad, supervisor job needs to be an argument of a scope in order to function, it does nothing when used with coroutine builder. But in this case it's easier to use [`supervisorScope`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/supervisor-scope.html) builder to create a nested scope.